# Semantic Web and structured data - Will search engines increase the limit of the first number of indexed bytes on a page?

Tags: seo, structured-data, semantic-web, page-size

A web page's payload will increase with the added code that is necessary to create structured data.  This means that you won't be be able to fit as much actual content in the first 120k or so of the page.

Has there been any discussion about this in the past, and if so, what are the chances that this limit will be increased to allow for more data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think this hasn't happened already/doesn't happen continuously?
I remember a point where pages were recommended to stay below ~40k **total**. With pages easily averaging over 1.2M or so more recently, it would just be insane to think whatever that cutoff is doesn't get periodically adjusted.

The real "problem" you're bringing up is that no engine is likely ever going to publicize a specific number. It wouldn't be very useful anyway, as that number alone doesn't tell you much of anything except in very simple, specific cases. A large page isn't necessarily even top-heavy, for that matter.

It's also likely–this is speculative, but plausible–that the content being "early" in the document is much less of an issue than it may have been in the past. There are methods of determining what the main content of a document is(think of how Instapaper works) that it would be trivial to apply here with Google's resources.

A more useful and interesting number is page *loading* time, which definitely *is* [known to be a ranking factor](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/). Though again note that even a very small piece of Javascript could slow down your page loading if it does something stupid.

Comment: does using the defer in the script tag help in reducing the page load times?

Comment: @Prasad *Techniques* for reducing page load times are outside the scope of this topic. (Also, I have no idea if defer has any effect on spiders versus users, and it's unclear which you're asking about, etc.) Start a new one, if you like. Admittedly I've already pushed things beyond the initial question myself, but that's because I think it was flawed in the first place.